# Ruby on Rails: Unfollow users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure why this does not allow current user to unfollow users. When "unfollow" button is clicked, the page gets routed to /friendships?friend_id=2 and this error message: No route matches [DELETE] "/friendships" appears

**_user.html.erb**

```
 <%= link_to "Unfollow", friendships_path(friend_id: user.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class:"btn btn-md btn-danger" %>
```

**friendship controller**

```
def destroy
  @friendship = Friendship.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @friendship.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
  redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :friendships, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "friend_id"
    t.boolean "accepted", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using singular friendship_path not plural form (friendships_path)

```
<%= link_to "Unfollow", friendship_path(current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(u‌​ser.id)), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class:"btn btn-md btn-danger" %>
```